# regex search replace contries list

Tags: regex, replace

i have a list of countries for a dropdown and i want to make some modifications on it.
exemple :

```
<option value="honduran">Honduran</option>
```

must become

```
<option value="honduran" <?php if ( $cand_nationality == 'honduran') { echo "selected"; } ; ?>>honduran</option>
```

and i want to use this list
https://gist.github.com/didats/8154290

how can i get the full list with this modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try below python **regular expression**

```
import re

data = '<option value="honduran">Honduran</option>'

print(
    re.sub(
        r'<(option) (value="(.+)")>(.+</option>)',
        r'''<\1 \2 <?php if ($cand_nationality == '\3') { echo "selected"; } ; ?>>\4''',
        data
    )
)
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get that

Comment: i want to make this for all option here
https://gist.github.com/didats/8154290
not for only honduran

Comment: can you try now. I changed the regex